# Value never below zero

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, numeric, zero

Is it possible to assign a numeric value to a variable in such a way that it is limited to a certain range? More specifically I want a variable that can never go below zero, because if that was about to happen an exception would be raised.

Imaginary example:

```
>>> var = AlwaysPositive(0)
>>> print var 
0
>>> var += 3
>>> print var 
3
>>> var -= 4 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
AlwaysPositiveError: dropping AlwaysPositive integer below zero
```

The reason I ask is because I am debugging a game I am writing. Where humans understand implicitly you can never have `-1` cards in your hand, a computer does not. I can make functions that check all values used in the game and call those functions at multiple positions throughout the script and see if any weird values appear. But I was wondering if there perhaps was an easier way to do this?

Comment: what laguage do You use?

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't specify.. Python 2.7.10

Comment: If it's going to be an attribute, you could use a descriptor to enforce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-classing `int` is probably the best way to do this if you really need to, but the implementations shown so far are naive. I would do:

```
class NegativeValueError(ValueError):
    pass


class PositiveInteger(int):

    def __new__(cls, value, base=10):
        if isinstance(value, basestring):
            inst = int.__new__(cls, value, base)
        else:
            inst = int.__new__(cls, value)
        if inst < 0:
            raise NegativeValueError()
        return inst

    def __repr__(self):
        return "PositiveInteger({})".format(int.__repr__(self))

    def __add__(self, other):
        return PositiveInteger(int.__add__(self, other))

    # ... implement other numeric type methods (__sub__, __mul__, etc.)
```

This allows you to construct a `PositiveInteger` just like a regular `int`:

```
>>> PositiveInteger("FFF", 16)
PositiveInteger(4095)
>>> PositiveInteger(5)
PositiveInteger(5)
>>> PositiveInteger(-5)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    PositiveInteger(-5)
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 8, in __new__
    raise NegativeValueError()
NegativeValueError
```

See e.g. [the datamodel docs on numeric type emulation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) for details of the methods you will need to implement. Note that you don't need to explicitly check for negative numbers in most of those methods, as when you `return PositiveInteger(...)` the `__new__` will do it for you. In use:

```
>>> i = PositiveInteger(5)
>>> i + 3
PositiveInteger(8)
```

---

Alternatively, if these non-negative integers will be attributes of a class, you could enforce positive values using the [*descriptor protocol*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), e.g.:

```
class PositiveIntegerAttribute(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, typ=None):
        return getattr(obj, self.name)

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        if not isinstance(val, (int, long)):
            raise TypeError()
        if val < 0:
            raise NegativeValueError()
        setattr(obj, self.name, val)

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        delattr(obj, self.name)
```

You can then use this as follows:

```
>>> class Test(object):
    foo = PositiveIntegerAttribute('_foo')


>>> t = Test()
>>> t.foo = 1
>>> t.foo = -1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    t.foo = -1
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 13, in __set__
    raise NegativeValueError()
NegativeValueError
>>> t.foo += 3
>>> t.foo
4
>>> t.foo -= 5

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 1, in <module>
    t.foo -= 5
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 13, in __set__
    raise NegativeValueError()
NegativeValueError
```

Comment: Thank you. Not sure whether I will use it, but it improves my understanding of python either way.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `int`-derivation leaves out the interesting detail of overriding the operator methods which is the actual tricky part ...

Comment: @dhke not really; most of them will be completely trivial (`__add__` is `return PositiveInteger(self + other)`, `__sub__` is `return PositiveInteger(self - other)`, etc.)!

Comment: `self + other` does not that call `__add__()` again?

Comment: @dhke yes, you're right - you would have to access `super`/`int`. I will add an example

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass your own data type from `int` and provide it with [a bunch of magic methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) overloading the operators you need.

```
class Alwayspositive(int):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Alwayspositive, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __neg__(self):
        raise AlwayspositiveError()

    def __sub__(self, other):
        result = super(Alwayspositive, self).__sub__(other)
        if result < 0:
            raise AlwayspositiveError()
        return result
```

And so on. This is quite a lot of work and debug to make such a class safe, but it will allow you to debug your code with a very little changes between debug and release mode.

Comment: Note the result of `Alwayspositive(-1)`, or `-Alwayspositive(-1)` - this is a very naive implementation

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 Great answer, but for the time being a bit over my head I think. I will get stuck in though starting with reading up on the magic methods. As well as reading up on other examples of subclassing int.